# LINQ with SQL Data Adaptor

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is it possible to run LINQ to get desirable data from SQL Data Adapter. I've already got a SQL Data Adapter with data loaded from the database. What I would like to do is to get total count of rows from SQL Data Adapter filter by ("status") column (either 1 or 0).

I've tried with data table but in this case, I need to use the SQL Data Adapter.

Or, is it not a good idea at all? Please advice me as I'm still a learner.

Comment: SQLDataAdapters do not hold data in them -- you use them to load data into a dataset or datatable. So maybe you can show your code here to give us a better idea of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL queries to get data from database? If so you need to add filtering expression to that query like `WHERE status = 1`. Another option is to load data into datatable and [apply filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

P.S. You can always switch to Entity Framework and have all porer of LINQ in your hands